# Guideline for use of definite and indefinite articles in source code documentation

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I have a doubt about proper use of definite and indefinite articles is source code documentation.

For example:

```
/**
 * Opens the door.
 *
 * @param speed The opening speed in cm/s.
 * @param alarm The alarm that is turned on while the door is opening.
 * 
 * @returns The promise that is resolved once the door is fully open.
 */
 open(speed: number, alarm: Alarm): Promise<void>;
```

and

```
/**
 * Opens the door.
 *
 * @param speed An opening speed in cm/s.
 * @param alarm An alarm that is turned on while the door is opening.
 * 
 * @returns A promise that is resolved once the door is fully open.
 */
 open(speed: number, alarm: Alarm): Promise<void>;
```

In the second example, the description of 'speed' is not right. However, I am not completely sure about the use of the articles in the 'alarm' description and in the return description.

Which is better in each case and why? Is there a grammar rule that justifies a decision or a best practice here?

Comment: Use definite articles here, or omit them in such notes. It may depend on context though: a `promise` might be a random selection, rather than something specific.

Comment: Each time the function is called there is only one of each parameter and only one returned value. If I have to read the documentation to find out how the code works I'm only interested in what the code does when it's called, the fact that it can be called thousands of times is irrelevant to the reader of the documentation in that context. I'd use the definite article.

Comment: I agree with both comments. The value entered may be “a” value selected from a range of possible values but it is “the” one and only entered value. Similar to maths conventions of defining terms in equations. For example, V=f.t, where V is the velocity, f the acceleration, and t the time. Nobody would use the indefinite article in those definitions.